# How to display text with spaces in HTML

Tags: html

here I have an example. how can I display this text on my html page as is?

I tried using `&nbsp` for spaces and `br` for lines, br seemed to work but &nbsp did not.

`````
                   -`
                  .o+`
                 `ooo/
                `+oooo:
               `+oooooo:
               -+oooooo+:
             `/:-:++oooo+:
            `/++++/+++++++:
           `/++++++++++++++:
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:
 `++:.                           `-/+/
 .`                                 `
`````

Here is Code snippet to check how it's rendered

`````html
<p>
                       -`
                      .o+`
                     `ooo/
                    `+oooo:
                   `+oooooo:
                   -+oooooo+:
                 `/:-:++oooo+:
                `/++++/+++++++:
               `/++++++++++++++:
              `/+++ooooooooooooo/`
             ./ooosssso++osssssso+`
            .oossssso-````/ossssss+`
           -osssssso.      :ssssssso.
          :osssssss/        osssso+++.
         /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-
       `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-
      `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:
     `++:.                           `-/+/
     .`                                 `
</p>
`````

Comment: THere should be a semicolon after p like this &nbsp;

Comment: I just can't do that for every space.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [preformatted text element: `<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)—it renders text and whitespace exactly as written, using a monospaced font.

`````html
<pre>
                       -`
                      .o+`
                     `ooo/
                    `+oooo:
                   `+oooooo:
                   -+oooooo+:
                 `/:-:++oooo+:
                `/++++/+++++++:
               `/++++++++++++++:
              `/+++ooooooooooooo/`
             ./ooosssso++osssssso+`
            .oossssso-````/ossssss+`
           -osssssso.      :ssssssso.
          :osssssss/        osssso+++.
         /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-
       `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-
      `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:
     `++:.                           `-/+/
     .`                                 `
</pre>
`````

To make it more accessible for people using screen readers and other assistive technology, you could add an [image ARIA role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/img_role) to the `<pre>` element and provide alternative text, like so:

```
<pre role="img" aria-label="ASCII art of an upward-sweeping, triangular arrow.">
```

Comment: Seemed to work. Thanks. This is first time im hearing about 'pre'.

Comment: @tahatamer I highly recommend reviewing Mozilla's [HTML Element Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element). There's a bunch of great, lesser-used elements.